# Logical symbol for exclusive disjunction: fwwf

Tags: symbols

Neither `detexify` nor the list of mathematical symbols yield what I am looking for:

A logical symbol for the truth-function (FWWF)(pq), in English "Neither p nor q", also called 'exclusive disjunction', that looks like that:

```
>--<
```

This is the symbol that was used in the logics course I attended (University of Zurich). It seems that this symbol is non-standard.

Does anyone know how to write it in LaTeX? 
or:
What symbol *is* the standard?

Some suggestions:

```
\oplus 

\downarrow

\veebar
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Logicians don't agree even on the simbol for the implication, let alone with a rarely used connective. :) There is no standard, in other words.

Comment: Exclusive disjunction doesn't have the meaning 'neither... nor..'. It means '... and... but not both'.

Comment: A xor B means "either A or B" or "A or B, but not both".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like

```
\def\hmm{>\joinrel\relbar\joinrel<}

$a \hmm b
```

perhaps?

[image]